# socket.io.js not found in express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, chat

my folder structure for socket.io is as following:

> - node_modules/socket.io/

my folder structure for `socket.io.js` is as following:

> /node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http= require('http').Server(express);
var io= require('socket.io') (http);
var app = express();

 io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat',msg);
    });
 });

io.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('user is disconnected');
});
```

And **view** is as follows:

```
<script src="/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
    var socket= io();
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        socket.emit('chat', $('#input').val());
        $('#input').val('');
    return false;
    });

    socket.on('chat', function(msg){
        $('#sent').append(msg);
    });        
});     
</script>
```

and **errors** are:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Without creating server you are creating socket instance ,you can  pass app to your socket.js or you can export socket to other module and use accordingly....It should be like this

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  
var server = require('http').createServer(app);  
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, a node.js server does not server ANY files by default.  For a file to be served by the server, there must be a route handler that has code to send that particular file.  So, that explains why this doesn't work:

```
 <script src="/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
```

because there is no route handler in your server for the path `"/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"`.

But, socket.io solves this problem for you.  The socket.io server automatically installs a route for:

```
/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

And it will reach into that node_modules/socket.io/client directory and send the socket.io.js file when it sees the above request.

So, change your script tag to this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

And, the socket.io server will automatically send the socket.io.js file from the dist directory.

---

It looks like your server initialization is also not correct because you don't pass `express` to your http server, you pass `app`.  Change this:

```
var express = require('express');
var http= require('http').Server(express);
var io= require('socket.io') (http);
var app = express();

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat',msg);
    });
 });

io.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('user is disconnected');
});
```

to this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(80);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat',msg);
    });
 });

io.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('user is disconnected');
});
```

or, a bit simpler version:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(80);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat',msg);
    });
 });

io.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('user is disconnected');
});
```